# Java char variable

Tags: java, variables, types, char

The following code within a program allows `90` to be assigned to the variable 'ch'. 'Z' is then printed to the console.

```
char ch;
ch = 90;
System.out.println(ch);
```

However, the following code, that lies within a program, does not compile. If the following code requires the input to the `ch` variable to be a character type, i.e. `(char) System.in.read();`, then why does the same not apply when `90` is assigned to `ch` above? Why doesn't it have to be `ch = (char) 90`?

```
char ch;
ch = System.in.read();
```

Comment: This is covered in [Chapter 5: Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-200-A) in [the Java Language Specificiation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler knows that `90` is a valid value for `char`. However, `System.in.read()` can return any `int`, which may be out of the valid range for `char`s.

If you change 90 to 90000, the code won't compile:

```
 char ch;
 ch = 90000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are dealing with system io you need to ensure that you can handle all valid byte input values. However, you then need a mechanism to indicate that the stream has been exhausted. The javadoc for [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) ([`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is a global `InputStream`) says (emphasis added),

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. **If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.**

If you were to cast `-1` to `char` you would get 65535 because `char` is unsigned. With `byte`, it's even worse in that `-1` is a valid value. Regardless, you aren't reading `char` values; you are reading `byte`(s) encoded as `int` in the range 0-255 plus -1 to indicate end of stream. If you want `char`(s) I suggest you look at an [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) which is described in the javadoc as

> An `InputStreamReader` is a bridge from byte streams to character streams